# How to install Google Assistant SDK on MacOSX

Tags: python, macos, google-assistant-sdk

The documentation of [Google Assistant SDK](https://developer.google.com/assistant/sdk) list Raspberry Pi has a supported platform, are the [Python samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python) compatible with MacOSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Google Assistant SDK samples have been designed to work on Raspberry Pi, the Python samples primarly use [sounddevice](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sounddevice) and [grpcio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grpcio/1.2.1) packages, and both provide python wheels for MacOSX, so it should work with minimal effort.

- Download [Python 3.x for MacOSX](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/)
- Create a virtualenv

  ```
  python3 -m venv env
  env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
  source env/bin/activate
  ```
- Install the SDK

  ```
  (env) $ pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]
  ```
- Run the sample

  ```
  (env) $ googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk
  ```

Comment: Did u test this actually or just copy paste it?

Comment: Didn't work
`Error while finding spec for 'googlesamples.assistant' (<class 'ValueError'>: googlesamples.assistant.__spec__ is None)`

Comment: @krisdestruction updated the snippet to match the last release of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Google Assistant demo written in Go running on Mac (and should compile fine for Windows too)
https://github.com/mattetti/ok-go

Answer (score 0):

I've got a native macOS app working. It sits in the menu bar and accepts commands. However, it is written in Swift 3.1, not Python. You can find it [here](https://github.com/vanshg/MacAssistant/)